# Can I use unix sort to sort a file on multiple keys of different types (mix of strings and numbers)?

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a delimited text file of multiple columns some of which are text and some of which are numbers.  I would like to sort on multiple fields, wich span both text and numerical fields.  While -n allows treating things as numbers, it does strange things with text, and omitting that results in numbers being treated like text.  Is there a way I can associate a field with a treatment?

**EXAMPLE:**

Input file:

```
Doggy,20
Cat,20
Cat,5
Bird,100
Bat,5
```

Desired sort based on first field, then second:

```
Bat,5
Bird,100
Cat,5
Cat,20
Doggy,20
```

Result of `sort input.txt -t, -k1,1 -k2,2`:

```
Bat,5
Bird,100
Cat,20
Cat,5
Doggy,20
```

*note: Cat,20 precedes Cat,5*

Result of `sort input.txt -t, -n -k1,1 -k2,2`:

```
Bat,5
Cat,5
Cat,20
Doggy,20
Bird,100
```

*Note: Bird,100 is last*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the `n` for numeric treatment to only the field(s) that you want sorted as such. In your example data, field 1 is text and field 2 is numeric, so add the `n` only to the definition of field 2:

```
sort input.txt -t, -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

or

```
sort input.txt --field-separator=, --key=1,1 --key=2,2n
```